# How to draw fb demographics using rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am looking for a rails graph and how to bring face book insights of demographics statics information into rails application.

[image]

Any suggestion how to draw demographics and Auth Dialog detail in rails ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I that this is old post...but I'm looking for same thing...have you found whats good out there?

Comment: @Xander -I didn't get any guide